# How does IP store in Buffer using "inet_ntop()"

Tags: c, linux, packet-sniffers

I have written a packet sniffer code everything is working but I want to separate packets from specific IP. To do so i need to access the buffer, which stores the IP address by using inet_ntop(). How can i compare "sbuf/dbuf" with specific IP. I tried by storing the IP in another 'char' array and compare them but it didn't work.

This is my code for IP's of incoming packets;

```
/* Parse IP protocol */
        struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr*) next_hdr;
        char sbuf[32];
        char dbuf[32];          
        printf("\tIP version: %u ihl: %u ttl: %u protocol: %u src: %s dst %s\n",    
            ip->version,
            ip->ihl,
            ip->ttl,
            ip->protocol,
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ip->saddr, sbuf, sizeof(sbuf)),
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ip->daddr, dbuf, sizeof(dbuf))
        );
```

Just help me in comparing specific IP with  incoming packets, i'll do the rest.

I am stuck at this for a while now. HELP... !!!

I am working on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it the other way round; convert the IP you are looking for into an integer and compare that directly with `ip->saddr`:

```
in_addr_t x = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");
if (x == ip->saddr) {
    // Do something
}
```

This should be more efficient and the better way to go.

Comment: Ohh damn... why it didn't occur to me to use `in_addr_t`... how dumb am i... Thank you so much brother...